# Flutter app using Dart to parse a Map - throws exception for a double

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a factory method, as shown below, where I am trying to obtain a value from a map as a double.

The value in the map is set as "buyNowAmount": 0, but fails when trying to convert it to a double, with a message that "int is not a subtype of double".  So, I have to catch the exception as shown below.

When this same code is put in Dartpad, it works without throwing an exception.

I would prefer not to have to catch an exception.

```
  factory Auction.fromJSON({required Map<String, dynamic> json}) {
    double? tempBuyNowAmount;

    if (json['buyNowAmount'] != null) {
      try {
        tempBuyNowAmount = json['buyNowAmount'] as double;
      } catch (e) {
        tempBuyNowAmount = (json['buyNowAmount'] as int).toDouble();
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call `json['buyNowAmount'].toDouble()` unconditionally.  Since `json['buyNowAmount']` is of type `dynamic`, you don't need to perform an explicit cast before attempting to call a method on it.  Additionally, `double` has a `toDouble()` method (inherited from `num`) that will end up doing nothing.

If you feel the need to cast (maybe because you want a `TypeError` to be thrown instead a `NoSuchMethodError`), then you could do `(json['buyNowAmount'] as num).toDouble()` if you really want.

You additionally could replace the `if (json['buyNowAmount'] != null)` check with:

```dart
double? tempBuyNowAmount = json['buyNowAmount']?.toDouble();
```

Comment: @Nagual `tryParse` works on `String`s.  `JsonDecoder` from `dart:convert` will already have converted things that look like numbers into `int` or `double` types.  You also can tell from the original question that `json['buyNowAmount']` is either an `int` or a `double`; if it were a `String`, then both casts would fail.

Answer (score -1):

```
double tempBuyNowAmount = json['buyNowAmount']/1;
 //or
double tempBuyNowAmount = double.parse(json['buyNowAmount'].toString());
 //or
double tempBuyNowAmount = json['buyNowAmount'].toDouble();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this part of code:

```
 try {
        tempBuyNowAmount = json['buyNowAmount'];
        tempBuyNowAmount = double.parse(tempBuyNowAmount);
      }
```